# How can I verify only certain properties using the Verify() method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

The following will evalute to true if the method `SendToTarget` is getting called with a type of `Message`.

```
// Arrange
var osmMock = new Mock<OrderStateMachine>(MockBehavior.Strict, mapper, sessionId, repo);
osmMock.Setup(m => m.SendToTarget(It.IsAny<Message>())).Returns(true);
var osm = osmMock.Object;

// Act
// ...

// Assert
osmMock.Verify(m => m.SendToTarget(It.IsAny<Message>()), Times.Once);
```

This however is very broad.

I would like to test that the method `SendToTarget` was called with an instance of `Message` having set a specific property to a specific value.

Sure I could pass an instance of `Message` to the method like this `osmMock.Verify(m => m.SendToTarget(It.Is(myMessageInstance)))`. But I don't want to verfiy against a completely propagated instance of `Message`.

All I want is to verify that a specific property of the `Message` type is set to a specific value. I hope it's clear what I am trying to archive. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you try `It.Is<Message>(m => property_to_check)`? Btw, how does `Message` look like?

Comment: Thank you that solves my problem. If you add it as answer I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `It.IsAny<Message>()` you can use `It.Is<Message>` with custom expression `Expression<Func<Message, bool>>` to verify the property value of passed `Message` instance, something like that

```cs
osmMock.Verify(m => m.SendToTarget(It.Is<Message>(m => m.SomeProperty == someValue)), Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `Verify` with `It.Is<Message>(Expression<Func<Message, bool>> match)`. Then you can check arbitrary conditions within that delegate, e.g. if you have a `string` property:

```
osmMock.Verify(m => m.SendToTarget(It.Is<Message>(x => x.YourProperty == "some value")), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question. But Pavel was quicker. I am sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Add another Assert and check the property? The message being an object, it is passed by reference and you can take a peak.

Comment: It looks like a comment, not the answer